# Irregular Polygon

Tags: wpf, xaml

Take a look at the attached pic, I need to mimic the grey irregular polygon header at the top of the form. If it wasn't for the angled portion on the right-hand side, it would be straightforward. What is the best method to create it? Can this be created in XAML? Should I use an image? Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done via the standard drawing capabilities in XAML.  See [Shapes and Basic Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx) for details on making custom shapes.

Comment: well, I appreciate the response but this gets me nowhere... I need this object to "dock" to the top of the window. "Anchoring" to the top and both sides, to be resized horizontally with the form. How do you dock and or anchor in wpf?

Comment: @user1017477 There are a lot of options in WPF - `DockPanel` is the closest to "Dock", but I personally prefer just using a Grid and setting `ColumnDefinition` to fixed size / Auto / * to fit in

Comment: Thanks again for the follow up and I apologize for my lack of wpf knowledge but this is my first project coming from winforms... Should this be created using a <polygon> and specifying the points? If so, how would I dock this to the three sides? Or, should I create this with a series of <lines> and then fill it?

Comment: @user1017477 I would just try to handle the diagonal portion as it's own Path, and draw it.  Look at the shapes article I linked, in particular: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx#fillpaint

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using the grid for the layout then placing a triangle in one cell and the wedge shape in the other did the trick. Really easy once I figured it out ;)